# WPF - IsLargeArc="false" doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, path

I recently wanted to use an `ArcSegment`, but however the `IsLargeArc="False"` doesn't work. Here is example code with a picture of the compiled application.

The picture is:

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="1000">
    <Canvas Height="500" Width="500">
        <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="50, 50">
                        <ArcSegment Point="300, 50" IsLargeArc="False" Size="50,25" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="3">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="50, 250">
                        <ArcSegment Point="300, 250" IsLargeArc="True" Size="50,25" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: see [ArcSegment.IsLargeArc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.arcsegment.islargearc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

until the size of your arc does not allow two different rendering option `IsLargeArc` wont make any difference

try this xaml, I just modified the size of arc in your xaml

```
<Canvas Height="500"
        Width="500">
    <Path Stroke="Red"
          StrokeThickness="3">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="50, 50">
                    <ArcSegment Point="300, 50"
                                IsLargeArc="False"
                                Size="150,25" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Stroke="Green"
          StrokeThickness="3">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="50, 250">
                    <ArcSegment Point="300, 250"
                                IsLargeArc="True"
                                Size="150,25" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

result

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't fully understand what the [`ArcSegment.IsLargeArc` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.arcsegment.islargearc(v=vs.110).aspx) does... from the linked page:

> For most arcs of a particular position, size, and rotation, there are four different arcs that can be drawn; the `IsLargeArc` and `SweepDirection` properties indicate which arc to use.

So, removing your `Point` settings and adding the `SweepDirection` settings, we can see a clear difference:

```
<Canvas Height="500" Width="500">
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="50, 50">
                    <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="False" Size="50,25" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="50, 250">
                    <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Size="50,25" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```